# Contar as semanas entre duas datas

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando realizar uma query entre duas datas que me retorna o numero da semana e conta progressivamente a semana.

Como exemplo :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ficou assim :

```
SELECT ROUND((DATEDIFF(max(atendido_em_data),min(atendido_em_data)))/7) as semana,min(atendido_em_data) as min,max(atendido_em_data) as max
from ger_posicao;
```

Não entendo porque o banco continua a me retornar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você diz *contar progressivamente as semanas* pode significar muitas coisas.

Porém, no exemplo que você apresenta na pergunta eu não encontrei qual é o sentido, pois a semana 1 tem 3 dias, e os dias da semana (seg, ter, qua) não correspondem às datas na realidade (dia 30/04 foi uma Segunda ao invés de Domingo como o exemplo sugere).

De qualquer modo, O [MySql tem umas funções de data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) que você pode usar para resolver esse problema.

Nessa implementação, eu usei o [`Week(date, mode)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) e passei uma 'data base' para controlar a sequencia de contagem:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(data), 
       data, 
       CONCAT('semana ', WEEK(data,1) - WEEK('20180428',1) + 1) AS semana
FROM tabela
```

Veja esse exemplo funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17a10/16).

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 4):

Seria a função abaixo? ([publicada no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833261/mysql-week-calculation-between-two-dates))

`SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF('2018-05-20', '2018-04-30'))/7;`

Para obter o valor arredondado, como pediu nos comentários:

`SELECT ROUND((DATEDIFF('2018-05-20', '2018-04-30'))/7);`

Comment: Olá Cleber minha tabela esta setada como date e o formato esta assim 2018-04-30

Comment: Faça assim: `SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(nome_do_campo_com_maior_data, DATE(nome_do_campo_com_menor_data))/7);`

Comment: Ajustando conforme o Roberto me passou, tenho a data minima dia 2018-04-30 e a data maxima 2018-05-10, o calculo me retorna 1 sendo que o correto seria 3 igual ao print que postei.

Comment: Carlos, alterei meu exemplo. No caso não chegam a 3 semanas (o resultado será 2.85). Vc pode usar um ROUND() para obter 3 nesse caso.

Comment: Atualizei com o resultado adptado mas sem sucesso ainda.

Comment: @CarlosLopes, dá uma olhada de novo de usou este meu exemplo.. tentei aqui e foi sem problemas, obtive Resultado "3".